# Do I need to convert my time series to a stationary process when conducting a t-test on it?

Tags: time-series, t-test, stationarity

I have two time series, $X_{t}$ and $Y_{t}$. I want to know if there's a significant difference between them.

Step 1: get the differences between them $\textbf{d} = X_{t}-Y_{t}$

Step 2: calculate mean $\bar{d} = \frac{1}{n}\sum\textbf{d}_{i}$.

Step 3: Perform t-test on $\textbf{d}$:
$H_{0}: \mu_{X-Y} = 0; H_{A}: \mu_{X-Y} \neq 0$.

In step 1, would I need to convert X and Y to stationary processes?

Why am I asking this? I have no background in time series, I *think* I am in essence treating the data as cross-sectional. But I don't know if I can do that because I have seen that time series values are correlated which violates the independence assumptions of the t-test.
I do see that in time series analysis, the signals are often converted to stationary processes prior to analysis. I do not know why this is beyond having a sequence for which there can be a meaningful mean and variance, so I cannot determine if it is appropriate for me to convert to stationary process here.

Comment: Remember to use an appropriate estimator of the standard deviation of $\bar{d}$ (e.g. Andrews or Newey-West) to account for any autocorrelation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1. If $d_t$ forms a stationary process, you are OK.**

Two cases here:

**1A) Both $x_t$ and $y_t$ are stationary. Then you are testing if their means differ.

**1B) Both $x_t$ and $y_t$ are I(1), but co-integrated, with (1, -1) co-integration vector.  Then you are testing if the co-integration relationship is of zero mean.

**Case 2. If $d_t$ does not form a stationary process, you are not OK.**

First, it is not clear what you are testing.  Second, the computed statistic no longer has a T distribution.  Instead, it has a special distribution, depending on if $d_t$ is difference stationary or trend stationary, or something else.

Comment: Good answer. But just to clarify where you say stationarity you really mean I(0), right? Imagine in 1A that both x and y are non-stationary because of non-constant variances but are both I(0), what you wrote still stands.

Comment: I was under the maintained hypothesis that all series are 1) covariance stationary, which I call I(0), 2) difference covariance stationary, which I call I(1), or 3) time-trend covariance stationary.  I should have made that explicit.  It is not meant to be exhaustive of course.  Your example,  heteroscedasticity, is similar to I(0), whereas the T-stat (computed w/ HAC adjustment) on the difference would remain valid.